# PreparedStatement "like" pattern matching not working for filepath

Tags: java, h2

For my case I have version stored for each file, trying to find max version of files under a directory.

passing directory path to below method always returning 0 as pattern match failing with prepare statement.

```
public int getMaxVersion(String path) {
    int version = -1;
    String query = "SELECT MAX(VERSION) FROM TABLE WHERE FILENAME LIKE ?";

    Connection connection = database.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    if(connection != null) {
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, path + "%");
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()) {
                version = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            database.close(connection, pstmt);
        }
    }
    return version;
}
```

I have verified the table files are present under the directory.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
FILENAME            SIZE    VERSION  
C:\sb\pub\13.jpg    1032    2
C:\sb\pub\23.jpg    1562    3
(2 row, 2 ms)
```

I am using h2 db in embedded mode.

Can anyone please help me out what I am missing here?

Comment: it should return `-1` not `0` if nothing is found

Comment: hi singhakash max function always returns one record, if nothing matches then it returns null, rs.getObject(1) is returning null if nothing matches, but rs.getInt(1) returning 0, thats why I am getting 0 not -1.

Comment: How do you call the method, that is, what is `path`?

Comment: I am using directory path to call.
File dir = new File("C:\\sb\\pub");
int maxVersion = getMaxVersion(dir.getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash used in the like-expression is treated as an escape character, so that `%` and `_` can be escaped. In your case, you do not want that, so you have to either escape the backslashes with extra backslashes or disable escaping altogether by altering the SQL to:

```
SELECT MAX(VERSION) FROM TABLE WHERE FILENAME LIKE ? ESCAPE ''
```

... where the empty string represents *no escape*. See [the H2 SQL grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#condition_right_hand_side) for more details.